# Dumping Miscellaneous R Objects into .TXT

Tags: r

I have a bunch of straggler objects from a broader (otherwise well-formatted) process. These guys are basically small summary df's - 3x4's, 5x5's, one 3x20, etc. I want to get all of these small objects into a single text file.

Rather than take the time to align everything so that I could mash it together with `rbind()` or `data.frame()`, I'm expecting there may be some way to just dump outputs into a txt file, format be damned.

Is there something like that?

Toy df for example:

```
df <- data.frame("type" = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                 "time1" = round(rnorm(n = 4, mean = 100, sd = 35)),
                 "time2" = round(rnorm(n = 4, mean = 100, sd = 35)))
```

Comment: Checkout `?sink`

Comment: To make them re-readable for copy and paste in R, you could use the appropriately named `dump` for copy and paste as Latex or HTML tables, `knitr::kable` or `xtable::xtable` come to mind. Both of these can use a data.frame or a matrix as an argument.

Comment: So `sink` solves the immediate problem, but dump is actually pretty cool. Will experiment with that as well - thanks